# R [ggplot2] How to set ticks size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set ticks size, but when I specify axis.ticks parameter, ticks become horizontal on both axes. For example

```
data <- data.frame(x =c(1:10), y = c(1:10) )
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(size = 5))
```

http://prnt.sc/dlwv0i

And angle parameter doesn't work.

ggplot2 version 2.2.0.9000

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This does seem odd.  You can work-around it be adding something like `color = "black"` or `linetype = 1` in `element_line`.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help, but setting  `lineend = "square"` or `lineend = "round"` solves the problem. However it does't work with default `lineend = "butt"`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may do:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(.25, "cm"))
```

This is from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html

Comment: Thank you, the combination of axis.ticks.length and axis.ticks.size works perfectly